# Инициализация большого вектора в C++ из другой программы

Tags: c++, файлы, матрицы, vector

Изучаю C++.Есть процесс где содержится вектор с огромными данными, который имеет такую структуру:

```
   std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<double>>>
```

Так вот, программы работают не одновременно, то есть нужно как сохранить в каком то виде вектор потом я запускаю следующею программу и та должна скопировать данные из первой программы, которая к тому моменту должна быть завершена. Пытался сериализовать но не выходит:

```
std::ofstream os ("list.dat", std::ios::binary);                                    

size_t size1 = list1.size();                                                
os.write((std::vector<std::vector<double>>)&size1, 3);                                                   
os.write((std::vector<std::vector<double>>)&list[0], size1 * sizeof(list1));            
os.close();  

next programm>>>                                                                       
std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<double>>> list2;                                                                                                                      
std::ifstream is("list.dat", std::ios::binary);                                    
int size2;                                                                         
is.read((std::vector<std::vector<double>>)&size2, 3);                                                         
list2.resize(size2);                                                               
is.read((std::vector<std::vector<double>>)&list2[0], size2 * sizeof(???));                          
is.close();
```

Есть конечно вариант с обычной txt, но хотелось бы сделать по правильному

Comment: Чтобы записать вектор в файл, нужно отдельно каждый элемент вектора записывать, а не указатели на них. [Подробнее](https://www.cyberforum.ru/cpp-beginners/thread1078741.html) о записи вектора в файл.

Comment: В принципе, как запись в файл мне это помогло , а вот как считать с файла надо подумать, поскольку при чтении мне надо останавливаться и записывать в новый вектор

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Примерно так:

```
ostream& write(ostream& out, const vector<vector<double>>& d)
{
    size_t sz = d.size();
    out.write((char*)&sz,sizeof(sz));
    for(const auto& v:d)
    {
        sz = v.size();
        out.write((char*)&sz,sizeof(sz));
        out.write((char*)v.data(),sz*sizeof(double));
    }
    return out;
}

istream& read(istream& is, vector<vector<double>>& d)
{
    d.clear();
    size_t sz;
    is.read((char*)&sz,sizeof(sz));
    d.resize(sz);
    for(auto& v:d)
    {
        is.read((char*)&sz,sizeof(sz));
        v.resize(sz);
        is.read((char*)v.data(),sz*sizeof(double));
    }
    return is;
}


int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    vector<vector<double>> z = {{1,2,3},{9,8,7}}, t;

    ofstream os ("list.dat", ios::binary);
    write(os,z);
    os.close();

    ifstream is ("list.dat", ios::binary);
    read(is,t);
    is.close();

    cout << (z == t) << endl;

    for(auto x: z)
    {
        for(auto y: x) cout << y << " ";
        cout << "\n";
    }

    cout << "\n\n";

    for(auto x: t)
    {
        for(auto y: x) cout << y << " ";
        cout << "\n";
    }
        cout << "\n\n";
}
```

Обработку ошибок при открытии/записи/чтении допишите сами. Для тройного вектора - то же самое, с дополнительным уровнем рекурсии...

**Update**

Можно через шаблоны и специализацию - еще интереснее, уровень вложенности обработается автоматически...

```
template<typename T>
ostream& write(ostream& out, const vector<T>& d)
{
    size_t sz = d.size();
    out.write((char*)&sz,sizeof(sz));
    out.write((char*)d.data(),sz*sizeof(T));
    return out;
}

template<typename T>
istream& read(istream& is, vector<T>& d)
{
    d.clear();
    size_t sz;
    is.read((char*)&sz,sizeof(sz));
    d.resize(sz);
    is.read((char*)d.data(),sz*sizeof(T));
    return is;
}


template<typename T>
ostream& write(ostream& out, const vector<vector<T>>& d)
{
    size_t sz = d.size();
    out.write((char*)&sz,sizeof(sz));
    for(const auto& v:d)
    {
        write(out,v);
    }
    return out;
}

template<typename T>
istream& read(istream& is, vector<vector<T>>& d)
{
    d.clear();
    size_t sz;
    is.read((char*)&sz,sizeof(sz));
    d.resize(sz);
    for(auto& v:d)
    {
        read(is,v);
    }
    return is;
}
```

См. http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a7dd22c72f1f594b